# Regex to check empty spaces

Tags: regex

i have a text box but validates if length < 1. However if I use the keyboard space bar and enter empty spaces, the validation kept on button check does not work. Please help with a regex to check these blank spaces

Comment: What is your pattern you have tried?

Comment: What language are you using? The answer to your question is simple enough to be the same in most regex flavours, but the specific implementation may differ.

Comment: Why don't you accept any answer to this question? at least you should edit it to explain why those answers weren't good for you

Answer (score 4):

The regex `^\s+$`will match any string which is made entirely out of one or more white spaces. Take a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) regex tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This will match an empty string or any number of white-space characters: `/^\s*$/`